# Phonegap not calling deviceReady on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I have a perfectly functioning phonegap application running on droid devices.  However, when I move things over to iOS, the `deviceReady` method never fires.

**HTML HEADER**

```
<head>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi' name='viewport' />
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='stylesheets/application.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0rc2.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='stylesheets/application.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js'></script>
<script src='javascripts/application.js'></script>
<script src='javascripts/phonegap-1.2.0.js'></script>
</head>
```

**application.js**

```
$(function() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){alert(2)}, false);
});
```

If I stick an alert function in `$(function(){})` it fires, so I know jquery and application.js have loaded.  An `alert()` in phonegap.js also fires, confirming that that has also loaded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you using the phonegap-1.2.0.js from your Android app in the iOS one? In other words, did you copy it across as well?

PhoneGap has per platform phonegap-1.x.js files. Make sure you are using the one for iOS?

Comment: but where is the phonegap.js for iOS? It's not in the lib/iOs file in the phonegap folder.

Comment: This fixed it for me, wasted 2 days on this. The file should be named to the platform in my opinion.